# How to count common object of characters in R

Tags: r, character

I am not sure how to ask this question so I will put a title as close as I tried to ask, so please if you can find better way to phase, please fix it.

I have a  matrix, and column 1 is name of brands let's say "A","B" and "C" (there are 1212) and column 2 is a type of code. it is 4 digits and there are only one of them in each brand but it does not have to be in there as well.

```
> data3
      [,1] [,2]  
 [1,] "A"  "A012"
 [2,] "A"  "A001"
 [3,] "A"  "A123"
 [4,] "A"  "A005"
 [5,] "A"  "A004"
 [6,] "A"  "A100"
 [7,] "A"  "A023"
 [8,] "A"  "A055"
 [9,] "A"  "A044"
[10,] "A"  "A101"
[11,] "B"  "A012"
[12,] "B"  "A123"
[13,] "B"  "A005"
[14,] "B"  "A055"
[15,] "B"  "A044"
[16,] "B"  "A101"
[17,] "C"  "A032"
[18,] "C"  "A001"
[19,] "C"  "A323"
[20,] "C"  "A003"
[21,] "C"  "A011"
[22,] "C"  "A111"
[23,] "C"  "A013"
[24,] "C"  "A015"
[25,] "C"  "A014"
[26,] "C"  "A009"
[27,] "C"  "A011"
[28,] "C"  "A073"
[29,] "C"  "A063"
[30,] "C"  "A030"
[31,] "C"  "A028"
[32,] "C"  "A007"
```

How many of codes are common between A and B? and same thing for "A" and "C". This is an easy example which I can count by hand but since in real example it gets messy and I need to figure how to count.
My end goal to compute a number like [image] same for sim(A,C).

I initially thought to converting second column to a number with dropping "A"
for example

```
 [1,] "A"  12
 [2,] "A"  1
 [3,] "A"  123
 [4,] "A"  5
 [5,] "A"  4
```

then using | and other logic object but I could not convert a character to a number.

Comment: Do you need `lengths(combn(unique(data3$v1), 2, FUN = function(x) intersect(data3$v2[data3$v1==x[1]], data3$v2[data3$v1 == x[2]]), simplify = FALSE))`

Comment: Or another option is `lst1 <- split(data3$v2, data3$v1); combn(lst1, 2, FUN = function(x) intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]), simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: I think this question is similar and may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63259773/how-to-count-the-number-of-common-values-in-a-particular-group/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `%in%` operator in conjunction with `sum()` for this. But first, you need to transform the data a bit.

## Transform matrix to data frame

```r
# Convert to data frame. 
# Colnames will be set to "V1" (your column 1) and "V2" (your column 2) automatically
d <- as.data.frame(data3) 

# Filter data and extract variable
col2A <- d[d$V1 == "A", 2]
col2B <- d[d$V1 == "B", 2]
```

## Get number of common values

```
# check element-wise if value from col2A is in col2B
col2A %in% col2B
# Output: [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE (...)

# get number of common values 
sum(col2A %in% col2B)
```

Comment: I wrote a forloop to get all 

'M1=matrix(0,length(unique(d$V1)),5)
for(i in 1:length(unique(d$V1))){
  M1[i,1]="A"
  M1[i,2]=dim(d[(d$V1)=="A",])[1]
  M1[i,3]=unique(d$V1)[i]
  M1[i,4]=dim(d[d$V1==unique(d$V1)[i],])[1]
  M1[i,5]=sum(d[(d$V1)=="A",2] %in% d[d$V1==unique(d$V1)[i],2])
}'