# How to count the number of common values in a particular group?

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I have a data frame `df`.

```
df <- data.frame(shop = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                 product = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,5,2,4))
```

For every pair of shops i.e `AB`, `AC` and `BC`, I wish to count the number of common product.

The expected output is as follows

```
pair common_product
AB   1        # Because 1 is common
AC   1        # Because 2 is common
BC   2        # Because 5 and 4 is common
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A base R option would be :

```
pair <- combn(unique(df$shop), 2, paste0, collapse = "")
commmon_product <- combn(unique(df$shop), 2, function(x) 
      with(df, length(intersect(product[shop == x[1]], product[shop == x[2]]))))

data.frame(pair, commmon_product)
#  pair commmon_product
#1   AB               1
#2   AC               1
#3   BC               2
```

For every combination of `shop` values we find out how many `product` `intersect` using `combn`.

Comment: When I run code assigned to `pair`, I am getting the following error: `#Error in class(out) <- class(x0) : 
  adding class "factor" to an invalid object`

Comment: `df$shop <- as.character(df$shop)`

Comment: Thanks. You can remove one `m` from `commmon` if you want.

Comment: Is there a fast option? it takes forever to run!

Comment: If you have lot of unique values it is going to result in lot of combination of pairs.

Answer (score 0):

use `tidyverse`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(product) %>% 
  summarise(pair = str_c(shop, collapse = "")) %>% 
  count(pair)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  pair      n
  <chr> <int>
1 A         1
2 AB        1
3 AC        1
4 BC        2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
M1=matrix(0,length(unique(df$shop)),5)
for(i in 1:length(unique(df$shop))){
  M1[i,1]="A"
  M1[i,2]=dim(d[(df$shop)=="A",])[1]
  M1[i,3]=unique(df$shop)[i]
  M1[i,4]=dim(df[df$shop==unique(d$V1)[i],])[1]
  M1[i,5]=sum(df[(df$shop)=="A",2] %in% df[df$shop==unique(df$shop)[i],2])
}
```

It will return more than you want. Counts number of objects in "A","B" and "C"